# Giving my function access to outside variable

Tags: php, function, scope

I have an array outside:

```
$myArr = array();
```

I would like to give my function access to the array outside it so it can add values to it

```
function someFuntion(){
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;
}
```

How do I give the function the right scoping to the variable?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

By default, when you are inside a function, you do not have access to the outer variables.

If you want your function to have access to an outer variable, you have to declare it as `global`, inside the function :

```
function someFuntion(){
    global $myArr;
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;
}
```

For more informations, see [**Variable scope**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

But note that **using global variables is not a good practice** : with this, your function is not independant anymore.

A better idea would be to make your function **return the result** :

```
function someFuntion(){
    $myArr = array();       // At first, you have an empty array
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;      // Put that $myVal into the array
    return $myArr;
}
```

And call the function like this :

```
$result = someFunction();
```

Your function could also take parameters, and even **work on a parameter passed by reference** :

```
function someFuntion(array & $myArr){
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;      // Put that $myVal into the array
}
```

Then, call the function like this :

```
$myArr = array( ... );
someFunction($myArr);  // The function will receive $myArr, and modify it
```

With this :

- Your function received the external array as a parameter
- And can modify it, as it's passed by reference.
- And it's better practice than using a global variable : your function is a unit, independant of any external code.

For more informations about that, you should read the [**Functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) section of the PHP manual, and,, especially, the following sub-sections :

- [Functions arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)
- [Returning values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: @Machine : quite a good question ^^ *(I have, since, edited my answer a couple of time to add more informations ; maybe it was downvoted because not complete enough, at first... It probably has something to do with global, which people don't like...)*

Comment: @Machine Mr Anti-Global @Coronatus has decided that perfectly viable answers are wrong. And his 1,662 rep makes him right...

Comment: I read your initial version, it was still very much good enough for a +1 vote, and definitely not worth down-votes.

Comment: `global` method referrers to global variable, not outside!

Answer (score 43):

You can use an [anonymous function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures):

```
$foo = 42;
$bar = function($x = 0) use ($foo) {
    return $x + $foo;
};
var_dump($bar(10)); // int(52)
```

Or you can use an [arrow function](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2):

```
$bar = fn($x = 0) => $x + $foo;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Global $myArr;
$myArr = array();

function someFuntion(){
    global $myArr;

    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;
}
```

Be forewarned, generally people stick away from globals as it has some downsides.

You could try this

```
function someFuntion($myArr){
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;
    return $myArr;
}
$myArr = someFunction($myArr);
```

That would make it so you aren't relying on Globals.

Comment: The global inside the function scope whould be enough, did you add one to the 'main' scope intentionally? Good practice? (never using globals..)

Comment: The "global" outside the function is useless, unless the entire file was included from another function.

Answer (score 9):

```
$myArr = array();

function someFuntion(array $myArr) {
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $myArr[] = $myVal;

    return $myArr;
}

$myArr = someFunction($myArr);
```

Comment: The quality of this answer would be greatly improved if there was an explanation with the snippet.

Comment: passing variable to parameter function, great

Answer (score 4):

The one and probably not so good way of achieving your goal would using global variables.

You could achieve that by adding `global $myArr;` to the beginning of your function.
However note that using global variables is in most cases a bad idea and probably avoidable.

The much better way would be passing your array as an argument to your function:

```
function someFuntion($arr){
    $myVal = //some processing here to determine value of $myVal
    $arr[] = $myVal;
    return $arr;
}

$myArr = someFunction($myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**It really is about the correct order of things.**

```
<?php

/*In general(the rule can be broken) code is interpreted left to right
top to bottom.

If you want a function to be able to use the values you input,
write the function first. This means the function should be above where
it is requested in the code. Add some parameters($param). Note it does
not need to be called $param, I use $value in the example. This can be
multiple $vars going from left to right i.e($param_1,$param_2), or be an
array(), or a mix. Just remember left to right. Left values must exist
before right values.*/

//Example function here
function foo($value){
    
    return $value[0] + 1;

}

//Optional way to create array
//$value[0] = 0;

$value = array(0);
$limit = 10;

while($value[0] < $limit){
    
    //Request the function here as many times as you want
    echo $value[0] = foo($value);
    echo "<br>";
    
}

//Clean up afterwards
unset($value,$limit);

?>
```

Comment: There's so much unrelated code, it's hard to see the solutions you propose here.