# PHP: AJAX request to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, require-once

So I'm having a problem with including a file on a PHP page called from an AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#image-status").html('Processing images...');
});

function process_images(files) {
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/imageprocessor.php",
    data: {files: JSON.stringify(files)},
    success: function(data){  
        $("#image-status").html(data);
    }
});
}
```

I'm trying this require_once on imageprocessor.php:

```
require_once("db_connect.php");
```

Which is also in the include directory, and works: I just used it on another page to run an insert that worked just fine. But when I try to run:

```
function get_files($id) {
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM files INNER JOIN file_profile_join ON files.id = file_profile_join.file_id WHERE file_profile_join.profile_id = " . $id . " GROUP BY files.id");
try {
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetch();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
```

later on in imageprocessor.php, it errors out:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/yogabopvolume26/theprivatesector.org/epic/includes/imageprocessor.php on line 90
```

Like it's not requiring db_connect in the first place (that's where $db is declared). But it's also not returning an error that it can't find db_connect.php.

```
basename(__DIR__)
```

on imageprocessor.php (echoed through the AJAX request) returns "include."

I've tried using both an absolute URL and root path in the require_once, but then it neither errors out nor continues with imageprocessor.php: no echoes from that file after the require_once are returned. I also can't get the current session from session_start (I can print_r $_SESSION from the originary page [profile.php], so the session is active). Maybe they're related? I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Could you dump the content of $db? If you define a variable in external files, you must reference it using define() function.

Comment: would this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your `db_connect.php` is something link:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

And if you are using the connection object outside for your connection file, then you have to access that object into your particular file with the use of `global`

And as i know, you getting this error because you didn't called the object `$db` in your file `imageprocessor.php`, try with this:

```
function get_files($id) {
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM files INNER JOIN file_profile_join ON files.id = file_profile_join.file_id WHERE file_profile_join.profile_id = " . $id . " GROUP BY files.id");
    try {
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetch();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. Scope issue. It's late. Thanks, that did it. It's now returning a syntax error on my statement, so all good!

Comment: @Jeff http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/ here is a nice tutorial about PHP PDO, hope this helps you more..

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function someFunc() on a non-object in......

This type of error happens when you want to use the someFunc() method of any object, but unfortunately your object is not a object.

Suppose

```
$obj = New SomeObj();
$nextObj = $obj->someMethod(); // << Suppoes someMethod() returns a object if successfull
$nextObj->newMethod();
```

In this code, the `$nextObj->newMethod()` will work only when `$nextObj` is an object. But we cannot be sure about that because `$obj->someMethod();` will return an object only if successful, and returns otherwise when not successful.

A good way to prevent that would be.

```
$nextObj = $obj->someMethod(); // << Suppoes someMethod() returns a object if successfull
if(is_object($nextObj)){
    $nextObj->newMethod();
} else {
    //Now you know that there is error while executing $obj->someMethod();
}
```

**Another Thing:**
Since you have a function `function get_files($id)`. You can yourself see that `$db` variable is not defined within the scope of your function. So, $db contains nothing for now. AS in the other answers, you should use `global $db` or can pass the `$db` object as an argument to your function.