# Return an array from each function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an each loop function, i want to return an array outside the function.

```
//tried defining the array result outside the function, but whenever i printed the array it returning a empty array.

$test->each(function()){
//tried defining the array result inside the function, but whenever i printed the array its returning a undefined array.
   $result[] = "test";
}
echo json_encode($result);
//print array Undefined variable: result
```

EDIT:
i think when you use a closure in PHP, the variable inside the function is isolated. i need to convert it into foreach function.

Comment: Where do you define `result`? Show a full [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: i tried to define the result inside and outside the each function, whenever i define the result array outside, it is returning a blank array.

Comment: close parenthesis of `each`method  after function block, add a `use($result)` after empty function args list or better return the array

Comment: what is `$test`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable

Comment: i think when you use a closure in PHP, the variable inside the function is isolated. i need to convert it into foreach function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a closure in PHP, the variable inside the function is isolated. You need to convert it into foreach function so you can assign a value to array without a problem.