# getting a variable from a php function

Tags: php, function, global

I'm trying to set the image src from a variable which is defined in a function with a mysql query but it doesn't get the path.

Here is the function:

```
function bilderAbfrage($richtigesArray) {
 echo "ayy";
 $zahl = $GLOBALS["zaehler"];
 echo "$zahl";
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=datagame', 'root', 'root');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bilder WHERE DateIDFS = $richtigesArray[$zahl]";

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo $row['Path'];     // here it does print the right path of the image
        $bild1 = $row['Path'];
        $bild2 = $row['Path2'];
        $bild3 = $row['Path3'];
        $bild4 = $row['Path4'];

    }

}
```

Here are the images where it doesn't get the variables. I tried it with global but it didn't work:

```
<div class="row1">
        <img src="<?php global $bild1; echo $bild1; ?>" alt="<?php global $bild1; echo $bild1; ?>" id="pic1" class="pic1">
        <img src="<?php global $bild2; echo $bild2;?>" id="pic2" class="pic2">
        <?php echo "hey"; 
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <img src="<?php global $bild3; echo $bild3; ?>" class="pic3">
        <img src="<?php global $bild4; echo $bild4; ?>" class="pic4">
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving my function access to outside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable)

Comment: The `global` keyword goes *inside* your function `bilderAbfrage` declaration. See the link @Dharman mentions above.

Comment: omg, the mistake was, that i didnt global it in the function before giving them the path, I made them global after I gave them the path. Thanks for the help and yea i still have to make the prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

One little error I tried to make the bild1 - bild4 global after I gave them the path.

Correct:

```
function bilderAbfrage($richtigesArray){
echo "ayy";
$zahl = $GLOBALS["zaehler"];
echo "$zahl";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=datagame', 'root', '5718orii');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bilder WHERE DateIDFS = $richtigesArray[$zahl]";

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        global $bild1, $bild2, $bild3, $bild4;
        echo $row['Path'];
        $bild1 = $row['Path'];
        $bild2 = $row['Path2'];
        $bild3 = $row['Path3'];
        $bild4 = $row['Path4'];

    }

}
```