# How to set form values after the POST request calls a cURL and another function? global variable doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a simple form:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
  <input type="text" name="arg1"/>
  <input type="text" name="arg2"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then when it's submitted, I POST `arg1` via cURL and update its value based on the cURL response data. I then call another function to change `arg2` using a call to a Java program with `exec`.

And these two updated `arg1` and `arg2` should be the `value` attributes for that form after I submit it initially. (So that after the first submit, I just need to click "submit" as long as I keep getting data from the cURL request)

I tried using `global` as seen in this post: [Giving my function access to outside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable) ,but it doesn't work for me

My code is something like that:

```
   <form action="" method="POST"> 
      <input type="text" name="arg1" value="<?php echo $arg1;?>"/>
      <input type="text" name="arg2" value="<?php echo $arg2;?>"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form> 



<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {    

    $arg1_post = $_POST["arg1"];
    $arg2_post = $_POST["arg2"];
    $curl_post_fields = '{"arg1":' . $arg1_post . ', "arg2": "'. $arg2_post . '"}';
    
    sendCurlPost($curl_post_fields);

}

function sendCurlPost($curl_post_fields){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://url/" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $curl_post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 

    if ($response=curl_exec($ch)){
        global arg1;
        $arg1 = // some value from the $response

        $output=null;
        $retval=null;
   
        runJavaProgram();

    }
}

function runJavaProgram (){
    exec('C:\Java\jdk-18\bin\java.exe Main.java 2>&1 ', $output, $retval);   
    
    global $arg2;
    $arg2 = $output[0];
```

I keep getting `Undefined variable` even after the first POST. I also tried other methods using `SESSION` and `COOKIE` but that didn't work either

Comment: Which one is the undefined variable?

Comment: @nice_dev Both are

Comment: You mean $arg1 and $arg2?

Comment: Yes sorry about that (I see the `Undefined variable` message inside the form fields instead of the actual value)

Comment: Can you share full code if the file?

Comment: It's very long I will try to remove some unecessary stuff. But I think the issue could be the fact that I first POST the form, THEN I calculate the new values for `$arg1` and `$arg2`? So first the page refreshes, and only then it updates their values thus they're not appearing?

Comment: Where does `$arg2` come in? Should `runJavaProgram` have `$_POST["arg2"]`?

Comment: @user3783243 oh so you mean, once I get the value from the Java program, I should POST again? And this time post with both `$arg1` and `$arg2` after they've been updated? It's like two stages that require two post requests? One from the form, and then from the code? Also, nice_dev I updated the code and it really is almost the same as mine just without the calculations. The values in my real code are right because when I echo them it's the correct values