# Concatenating strings inside of Http::get()

Tags: php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$baseUrl = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=";
$api = "df87f0731def2f83a8539a2735b4c31ee";


class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $request){
        $responce = Http::get("https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=df87f0731def2f83a8539a2735b4c31ee2b6f0b5&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1");
        return view('index', ['responce' => $responce->json()]);
    }
}
//curl "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=df87f0731def2f83a8539a2735b4c31ee&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1"
```

I am trying to simplify string inside of get function by doing.

```
"{$baseUrl}{$api} . &interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1"
```

or

```
$baseUrl . $api . "&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1"
```

It seems not working.
Is there a recommendation of doing that ?
I just started learning PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: You don't need `.` if you're substituting the variables inside the string.

Comment: `"{$baseUrl}{$api}&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1"`

Comment: So it's just like this ??? $baseUrl$api"&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1" OR  "{$baseUrl}{$api}&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1" ????

Comment: If the variables are outside the quotes, you have to use `.` to concatenate them. If they're inside the quotes, you don't.

Comment: Barmar - I get ErrorException
Undefined variable $baseUrl

Comment: The variable is declared outside the function. Either pass it as a parameter or use `global $baseUrl;`

Comment: What does it look like if I want to use global ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531221/giving-my-function-access-to-outside-variable

Answer (score 0):

- You can format strings with [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).
- You can escape double quotes naturally in PHP, the braces just help for readability.
- You can concatenate single quotes and functions with `.`

PSB an example of each usage.

```
// Using format string functions
Http::get(sprintf('%s%s&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1', $baseUrl, $api));

// Escape - {} are not needed but increases readability
Http::get("{$baseUrl}{$api}&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1");

// Concatenate
Http::get($baseUrl . $url . '&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1');
```

You should also remember the scopes of your project and declare the variables correctly.

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    private string $baseUrl = 'https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=';
    private string $api     = 'df87f0731def2f83a8539a2735b4c31ee';

    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
        $response = Http::get(sprintf('%s%s&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1', $this->baseUrl, $this->api));
        return view('index', compact('response'));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, for learning purpose, could you show me how to set these variables globally and access from the function ?  using global ?

Comment: [You can read the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), maybe?

Comment: "$GLOBALS['baseUrl'] $GLOBALS['api'] &interval=1d,30d&convert=USD&per-page=100&page=1" seems not working....

Comment: The documentation simply states to just use `global $baseUrl, $api` inside the scope you want to use the variables. [See it working here.](https://3v4l.org/7A9N4)

Comment: Oh I got it thanks. but I think it's not good way to use in this case.

Comment: I address your issue in my answer by using [class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) which are declared inside of the class scope making them accessible using `$this` inside your class functions. You're going completely off the OP subject here.

Comment: I see GLOBALS in the documentation but not global. are they different ?

Comment: Accessing global variable inside function: The ways to access the global variable inside functions are:

Using global keyword
Using array GLOBALS[var_name]: It stores all global variables in an array called $GLOBALS[var_name]. Var_name is the name of the variable. This array is also accessible from within functions and can be used to perform operations on global variables directly.
This helpled

Comment: Yes, [which works perfectly fine](https://3v4l.org/C5mAi), also? What exactly are you asking now?